# Ошибка с reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, wordpress, recaptcha

```
Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element
    at Object.yr [as render] (VM7005 recaptcha__en.js:389)
    at bwpRecaptchaCallback ((index):1524)
    at VM7005 recaptcha__en.js:394
    at ir (VM7005 recaptcha__en.js:378)
    at VM7005 recaptcha__en.js:394
    at VM7005 recaptcha__en.js:405
```

Из-за этой ошибки могут не работать другие js файлы?

Сайт: http://brekety-almaty.kz/

Все контактные формы не автозаполняются при выборе адреса кроме той что находится в футере

Comment: Фома неверующий. Вам сказали в предыдущем вопросе - скрипты падают после ошибки. Вместо уточнения и разбора в том вопросе, вы предпочитаете флудить новыми вопросами.

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению! теперь я в тупике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь когда ошибки в консоли устранены, можно взяться за разбор происходящего.

Открываем dev tools, смотрим Event Listeners на форме на работающем сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что есть ссылка на 186 строку `http://viniry.kz/wp-content/themes/eurodent/js/scripts.js?ver=20151215`. Там находится код обработки. Если туда поставить точку останова в браузере, при клике сработает точка останова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На неработающем сайте такого обработчика (среди Event Listeners) вообще нет - проверьте это сами.

Почему так? В коде обработчика на картинке выше видим:

```
$('.contactform-wrap input[name="group"]').on('click',function(){
```

Клик должен быть по элементу input с name=group **внутри элемента с классом contactform-wrap**. У вас такого класс на проблемном сайте нет. Сравниваем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавьте класс к элементу, и всё будет работать.

Можно сделать вывод, что контент сайта переносился руками, и некоторые классы элементов Visual Composer были потеряны. И вот тут мы возвращаемся к самому первому моему вопросу - **как делали перенос сайта?** и убеждаемся, что с самого начала я вам не "мешался", и не "говорил не по теме", а указывал на первопричину ваших проблем.

Уверен, что из-за неправильного переноса у вас ещё не один косяк вскроется. Переносите сайты правильно, с использованием Duplicator, и вы избежите массы подобных проблем.

Comment: Вы мой герой спасибо